# C# overload function call on objects

Tags: c#

This is a wierd question but I thought about it and got curious:

Suppose I have a class:

```
public class Person{
    public String name;

    public Person(String _name){
        name = _name;
    }

    public void TellMyName(){
        Console.WriteLine(name);
    }
}
```

Then, somewhere in the code I create an instance of Person.

```
Person p = new Person("John");
```

Is there a way for me to write `p()` (as if it were a function call) and it trigger `p.TellMyName()`?

```
Person p = new Person("John");
p();

//output: John
```

Comment: You can invoke `TellMyName()` in the constructor. The question is, why would you want to do that?

Comment: No, you cannot overload `operator()`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/invocation-operator

Comment: I'm writing a class whose objects will be able to act as callbacks, so I got curious if this syntax was possible. As I want to call it at any moment, I don't think calling the function at the constructor is appropriate.

Comment: Then why don't define a delegate for that?

Comment: Why did you choose to expose the weird names? (I mean, the consumer code will see `_name`)

Comment: Can downvoters explain? I didn't see anything wrong with the question

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it is ok for you, you can accomplish the desired syntax by getting a delegate:

```
public class Person
{
    public string _name;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void TellMyName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_name);
    }
}

// ...

var o = new Person("John");
var p = (Action)o.TellMyName;
p();
```

Or you could change the constructor to a Create method and have this:

```
public class Person
{
    public string _name;

    private Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public static Action Create(string name)
    {
        return new Person(name).TellMyName;
    }

    public void TellMyName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_name);
    }
}

// ...

var p = Person.Create("John");
p();
```

Going the extra mile? Ok, here we go:

```
public class Person : System.Dynamic.DynamicObject
{
    public string _name;

    public Person(string name)
    {
        _name = name;
    }

    public void TellMyName()
    {
        Console.WriteLine(_name);
    }

    public override bool TryInvoke(
        System.Dynamic.InvokeBinder binder, object[] args, out object result)
    {
        result = null;
        if (args.Length == 0)
        {
            TellMyName();
            return true;
        }
        return false;
    }
}

// ...

dynamic p = new Person("John");
p();
```

Answer (score -1):

No you can't invoke a constructor likewise a normal method `p();` rather you invoke it while instantiating the object but yes you could do what you are looking for just by calling the method inside your `ctor` like

```
 public Person(String _name){
    name = _name;
   TellMyName();
}

private void TellMyName(){
    Console.WriteLine(name);
}
```